# AppDomain.UnhandeledException event not fired

Tags: wpf, events, crash, appdomain

In a WPF application, the app simply crashes, without the above event being fired.

(I'm also registered to DispatcherUnhandeledException, which doesn't fire as well.)

I conclude that it doesn't fire since the handler is defined to place a log entry. When looking at the log, there's no corresponding entry.

It happens in a production environment; I'm unable to point at a particular scenario.

I've read few descriptions on scenarios where this might happen, but I still don't have a clear grasp on this. Can anyone share his experience / knowledge on this?

How can I find the root of the crash and solve it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common causes for this would be a `StackOverflowException` or an `OutOfMemoryException`. To find the cause you could attach the Visual Studio Debugger and [enable all Exceptions](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/) in the Exceptions window. You will then be prompted when any exception occurs in your application.

Comment: It happens at production, and at no known particular scenario, so attaching a debugger isn't a relevant solution. Besides, I believe that a debugger won't catch it, since no exception is thrown.

Comment: You can not know if no excpetion is thrown. It could well be that your UnhandledExceptionHandler was just not able to catch it or wasn't able to log it.